# Accessing custom thumbnail options in templates

Tags: django, django-cms, django-filer, easy-thumbnails

In a Django CMS project with Filer enabled, the Admin dashboard for Filer allows you to create custom Thumbnail Options, similar to defining an alias using easy-thumbnails.

How do I access these options in templates?

`{{ obj.image.thumbnails }}` allows me to choose from one of the `DEFAULT_THUMBNAILS` defined in `abstract.py` in the Filer package, such as `admin_tiny_icon`, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to access these custom options defined in the front-end.

Thumbnail images are also not automatically created in `{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}` for these custom Thumbnail Options when adding new images like they are for the `DEFAULT_THUMBNAILS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own templatetag to get the desired thumbnail option, something like this:

```
// utils_tags.py

from django.template import Library

from filer.models import ThumbnailOption

register = Library()


@register.simple_tag
def get_thumbnail_option(name, filerimage):
    option = ThumbnailOption.objects.filter(name=name).first()
    if option:
        thumbnailer = filerimage.easy_thumbnails_thumbnailer
        return thumbnailer.get_thumbnail(option.as_dict)
    return filerimage
```

Then you could use it like this in a template:

```
{% load utils_tags %}

{% get_thumbnail_option "Custom thumbnail name" obj.image as thumb %}
```